# Dynamics CRM MessageBox

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have some JavaScript in Dynamics that does some work and needs to prompt the user with a Yes/No question.

I'd like to have the popup themed like the rest of Dynamics. Is there any page I can use with window.ShowModalDialog or some part of the API to provide a standard looking Dynamics message box?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, CRM doesn't have any function like that built in. You'll have to create your own page.

Answer (score 2):

there isn't a built-in feature to prompt the user in Dynamics CRM using javascript, however, you could build one the use the OpenDialog function to prompt it like Dynamics CRM does using one of these JS functions

```
Xrm.Utility.openDialog //2016
Xrm.Internal.openDialog //2015 - 2013
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a managed solution here https://alertjs.codeplex.com/

Comment: alert.js is great and is themed really well for dynamics. Give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

The latest Javascript API has the following method, its simple and amazing.

```
var confirmStrings = { text:"This is a confirmation.",cancelButtonLabel:"No", title:"Confirmation Dialog" };
var confirmOptions = { height: 200, width: 450 };
Xrm.Navigation.openConfirmDialog(confirmStrings, confirmOptions).then(
function (success) {    
    if (success.confirmed)
        console.log("Dialog closed using OK button.");
    else
        console.log("Dialog closed using Cancel button or X.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use "dialogs" and trigger that to open by using a javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dialog template found in the SDK to create a dialog with CRM 4.0 look and feel: 
(SDK Path)\visualstudiotemplates\cs\addonwebpage

Answer (score 0):

Hope that the below code snippet would be helpful

```
protected void doBatch()
{
    if (Box::yesNo("Vent radioactive gas?", DialogButton::No) == DialogButton::Yes)
    {
        super();
    }
}
```